# Android Bluetooth Devices Cached

Tags: android, android-widget, android-ndk

I'm facing a problem in my application that whenever I launch my application and click on a button to search the bluetooth devices (which 
scans the bluetooth devices from its around) my application  it does not always show the devices in range (sometimes it show one or more devices and sometimes a blank list appears). This is due the fact that the bluetooth devices are getting cached and on launching the app again it does not finds any new device. 
Same thing happening by manual scan from android device built-in option. I am trying with Samsung Galaxy GT-1900(2.2.1) and Samsum Nexus(4.0.2) . . 
Anyone can guide regarding this.
Thanks . . . .

Answer (score -1):

can you put some code?

you found android Bluetooth tutorial here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

i hope this will help you.